# Fabric.js : Change one or multiple selection square/rectangle color

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I'm working on a project that is using [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) library. What I want is to know how can I change the square/rectangle that appears when you want to select one or multiple object.

Is the blue rectangle in the image below:

[image]

I'm already changing some styling like corners color of object selection, the borders colors and so one like this:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.selection = !HelperJSViewBag.getValue("isMobile") && true;
fabric.Object.prototype.selectionColor = HelperJSViewBag.getValue("selectionColor").length > 0 ? HelperJSViewBag.getValue("selectionColor") : 'rgba(255,119,0,0.3)';
fabric.Object.prototype.rotationCursor = HelperJSViewBag.getValue('cursor_rotacao').length > 0 ? HelperJSViewBag.getValue('cursor_rotacao') : "crosshair";
fabric.Object.prototype.cornerSize = HelperJSViewBag.getValue("isMobile") ? (HelperJSViewBag.getValue("containerCornerSizeMobile") > 0 ? HelperJSViewBag.getValue("containerCornerSizeMobile") : 14) : (HelperJSViewBag.getValue("containerCornerSize") > 0 ? HelperJSViewBag.getValue("containerCornerSize") : 10);
fabric.Object.prototype.cornerColor = HelperJSViewBag.getValue("containerCornerColor").length > 0 ? HelperJSViewBag.getValue("containerCornerColor") : '#eee';
fabric.Object.prototype.borderColor = fabric.Object.prototype.cornerColor;
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
fabric.Object.prototype.borderScaleFactor = HelperJSViewBag.getValue("borderScaleFactor") > 0 ? HelperJSViewBag.getValue("borderScaleFactor") : 1;
fabric.Object.prototype.hasRotatingPoint = !HelperJSViewBag.getValue("isMobile") && true;
fabric.Object.prototype.rotatingPointOffset = HelperJSViewBag.getValue("isMobile") ? 20 : 35;
```

Comment: What you want to do?? change that box color?

Comment: We have several layouts of our application and each one requires to change the selection color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Canvas.prototype.set({
 selectionColor : 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
 selectionBorderColor :  'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)',
 selectionLineWidth : 10,
 selectionDashArray : [3,3]
});
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

You can override those selection properties.